# Escaping a PHP function as an Array value

Tags: php, drupal-8, dotenv

I'm working on a Drupal 8 starter kit with Composer, similar to [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project).

In my post-install script, I want to re-generate a `settings.php` file with my custom values.
I've seen that can be done with the [drupal_rewrite_settings](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21install.inc/function/drupal_rewrite_settings/8.2.x) function.

For example, I'm rewriting the `config_sync_directory` value like that :

```php
require_once $drupalRoot . '/core/includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once $drupalRoot . '/core/includes/install.inc';
new Settings([]);
$settings['settings']['config_sync_directory'] = (object) [
  'value' => '../config/sync',
  'required' => TRUE,
];
drupal_rewrite_settings($settings, $drupalRoot . '/sites/default/settings.php');
```

Problem is I want my Drupal 8 project to have a Dotenv so the maintainers don't have to modify the `settings.php` but only a `.env` file in the root folder of the project. To make it work, my `settings.php` must look like this :

```php
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => getenv('MYSQL_HOSTNAME'),
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'password' => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
  'port' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'username' => getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
];
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = explode(',', '^'.getenv('SITE_URL').'$');
```

As you can see, the values are replaced by PHP functions, and I can't see a good way to print those values, to the point I'm not even sure that's possible.

So my question is : is it possible to escape a PHP function as an Array value when declaring this variable ?

Comment: That drupal function is probably not prepared to handle cases like this. Its description reads, _“Replaces values in settings.php with values in the submitted array”_ - values, not “code”. I think you might have to write your own functionality here, that writes the necessary PHP _code_ to the settings file.

Comment: If you don’t want to completely re-invent the wheel - then maybe try and find some sort of “syntax” that allows you to specify your function calls in string form, and then after `drupal_rewrite_settings` has rewritten the settings file, you read its content as a string, replace what needs replacing, and write it back to the file again. Go with something that creates `'username' => 'FUNC[getenv("MYSQL_USER")]',` maybe, and then replace every occurrence of `'FUNC[xxx]'` with just `xxx` (removing the outer single quotes as well.)

Comment: I like your idea, I'll try it and see. My back-up plan is to have a custom PHP file with my variables that I'd programmatically copy-paste at the end of the re-generated `settings.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible because of the way the Drupal function works.

### Solution 1 by [@misorude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10283047/misorude)

Using the `drupal_rewrite_settings` function, we can add the value of settings as a String, like this :

```php
$settings['settings']['trusted_host_patterns'] = (object) [
  'value' => "FUNC[explode(',', '^'.getenv('SITE_URL').'$')]",
  'required' => TRUE,
];
```

And after that, we can replace all occurrences of `"FUNC[***]"` by `***` directly in the `settings.php` file.

---

### Solution 2

Put all your settings in a separate file. Example here, a `custom.settings.php` file :

```php
if (getenv('DEBUG') == 'true') {
  $settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/dev.services.yml';
  $config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
  $config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
}
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => getenv('MYSQL_HOSTNAME'),
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'password' => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
  'port' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'username' => getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
];
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = explode(',', '^'.getenv('SITE_URL').'$');
$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/files/private';
$settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/sync';
```

Then we can copy the `default.settings.php` and add our custom settings.

```php
$fs = new Filesystem();
$settings_generated = $drupalRoot . '/sites/default/settings.php';
$settings_default = $drupalRoot . '/sites/default/default.settings.php';
$settings_custom = $drupalRoot . '/../includes/custom.settings.php';
$fs->remove($settings_generated);
$fs->dumpFile($settings_generated, file_get_contents($settings_default) . file_get_contents($settings_custom));
```

There's also a [appendToFile](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/filesystem.html#appendtofile) method that seems way better than dumping a new file with `dumpFile`, but it was not working unfortunatly.